# php data separate file from website

Tags: php, arrays, file, serialization

On my website I show some products with their brand and model. This data is saved on the webpage via PHP.
Example:

```
<?php
    $producttype1 = array("01" => array("id"=>"01", "brand" => "ABC", "model" => "Hello"),
                         "02" => array("id"=>"02", "brand" => "ABC", "model" => "Hello"),
                         "03" => array("id"=>"03", "brand" => "ABC", "model" => "Hello"),
                         "04" => array("id"=>"04", "brand" => "ABC", "model" => "Hello"),
                         "05" => array("id"=>"05", "brand" => "ABC", "model" => "Hello"));
?>
```

These products are shown by this code:

```
<?php foreach($producttype1 as $z)
                { 
            ?>
            <a href="productdetail.php?type=producttype1&id=<?php echo $z["id"]; ?>&brand=<?php echo $z["brand"]; ?>&model=<?php echo $z["brand"]; ?>">
            <div class="product_box">
            <h3><?php echo $z["brand"]; ?></h3>
            <div class="image_box">
            <img src="images/producttype1/<?php echo $z["id"]; ?>.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <p><?php echo $z["brand"]; echo " "; echo $z["model"]; ?></p>
            </div></a>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

I want to access this data via a file called products.txt, so the data is not saved on the webpage.
Is there a way I can do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$fp = fopen("products.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, print_r($producttype1, true));
```

This will write the products array to a text file.

Comment: I would like to not use this data on my webpage, but access it via this file. So the data is not stored on the webpage, but on a textfile.

Answer (score 0):

```
$toBeWritten = $producttype1;

$fp = fopen("location/of/the/file/to/write.txt","a"); //replace file path as appropriate
fwrite($fp, serialize($toBeWritten)); // Serialization is easiest
fclose($fp);
```

Please note, that serialization can be reversed and the array can be usable again.
NOTE: Do not use the same file to store multiple arrays/objects/etc. as they will become corrupt.
To `unserialize` it again use:

```
$fileContents = '';
$fp = fopen("location/of/the/file/to/write.txt", "r");
$while !(feof($fp)) {
  $fileContents .= fread($fp, 1024);
}
fclose($fp);
$productstype1 = unserialize($fileContents);
```